# RuntimeException: Unable to create the cache directory (/var/www/sonata/app/cache/dev)

Tags: php, symfony, logging

I installed the *Sonata admin bundle*.
After installation i refresh my page there is the cache problem then i use the following command to remove the cache:

```sh
rm -rf app/cache app/log
```

Then I recreate the directory:

```sh
mkdir app/cache app/log
```

But I got the following error:

> **Runtime Exception** : Unable to create the cache directory (/var/www/sonata/app/cache/dev).

Answer (score 77):

It looks like a file/directory permission problem. The directory has to be writeable by the webserver. After creating the directory you should adjust the permissions with

```sh
chown -R www-data:www-data app/cache
chown -R www-data:www-data app/log
```

Or for *Symfony 4+*:

```sh
chown -R www-data:www-data var
```

This only works on linux systems. The user and group depends on your distribution. On *Debian* and *Ubuntu* this should be `www-data`, on *CentOS* it's afaik `apache`.

Another solution would be not to delete the whole folders but only their contents via

`$ rm -rf app/log/* app/cache/*`

But please be careful with this command.

Comment: I was having same issue on Ubuntu Server 16.04 and doing this `chown -R www-data:www-data var/logs var/cache var/sessions` resolved my issue, don't forget to clear cache..

Comment: Thanks. Similar solution for iTop if you encounter "RuntimeException : Unable to create the cache directory (/product/itop/itop/data/cache-production/twig/itop-core-update/...)".

Answer (score 10):

This solution is correct : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20128013/2400373

But is necessary change the 2 commands in `Symfony3`:
First you should is inside the folder of project:

```
$ sudo chown -R www-data:www-data var/cache
$ sudo chown -R www-data:www-data var/logs
```

After delete the cache:

```
$ sudo rm -rf var/cache/*
$ sudo rm -rf var/logs/*
```

Regards

Answer (score 6):

I solved it changing user and group of folder `var/cache` and `var/logs`, then I cleaned cache:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data var/logs
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data var/cache

sudo rm -rf var/logs/* var/cache/*
```

Comment: be careful with that `sudo rm -rf /var/logs/* /var/cache/*`  you are removing root cache !!    remove the slash bevor the `var `

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Vural Acar the answer was edited

Answer (score 4):

And for centos:

```
chown -R apache:apache app/cache
```

if you're coming here for Symfony Help you might have to do this as well if you delete the entire app/logs folder

```
chown -R apache:apache app/logs
```

Comment: it works Broks :) thanks , by the way can you explain me what is apache:apache ? why not the current user?

Answer (score 3):

I found a similar problem when I was using the PHP symfony as the error picture.
I found it after running command

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```

> I solved it by removed everything inside the folder **/app/var/cache**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is mostly the permission issue.

I have got resolved it on MAC using command: `$ sudo chmod -R 777 <path/to/cache/directory>`

You might try: `$ sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/sonata/app/cache`

Comment: This is the one that worked for me on Symfony 4 on Docker

Answer (score 1):

Changing the CHMOD might help but in case the cache annoys you during the deveopment you can just deactivate it.
Navigate to your app config file (located in ../app/config/config.yml from your root directory). Scroll to the twig configuration settings (under twig:) and change the cache value (which should be pointing to the cache directory) to false like so:

```
twig:
    cache:  false
```

If you do not see any cache configuration entry, simply add the line above.

Comment: of course you would need to reactivate it once the app is ready for production

Answer (score 1):

What is likely happening is that you are trying to create the file under apache/nginx. By default apache or nginx has umask set to 0022.

> From: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html
>
> Explain Octal umask Mode 022 And 002
>
> As I said earlier, if the default settings are not changed, files are created with the access mode 666 and directories with 777. In this example:
>
> The default umask 002 used for normal user. With this mask default directory permissions are 775 and default file permissions are 664.
>   The default umask for the root user is 022 result into default directory permissions are 755 and default file permissions are 644.
>   For directories, the base permissions are (rwxrwxrwx) 0777 and for files they are 0666 (rw-rw-rw).

You will need to manually set the umask to 0002, and reset it back to its previous setting before you can create the directories.

Answer (score 1):

On a **mac** computer it will be:

```
$ sudo chown -R _www:_www var/cache
$ sudo chown -R _www:_www var/logs
```

If **none of above work to you**, call a "phpinfo()" on your php file and find for "User/Group" value. That's the user group to give permission to.

Answer (score 0):

Also check the path. In my case, I had

`return dirname(__DIR__) . '../../../../var/cache/`

instead of

`return dirname(__DIR__) . '/../../../../var/cache/` (missing `/`)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with phpmyadmin 5.1.0

The solution was to specify the full path of the tmp directory, instead of relative path.

On the configuration file `config.inc.php` I had:

```
$cfg['TempDir'] = 'tmp'
```

I changed it to:

```
$cfg['TempDir'] = '/usr/share/phpmyadmin/tmp'
```

Seems that the problem is something related to "matching" with some allowed paths.
Maybe this solution can be extrapolated to other software that uses twig.

Answer (score -1):

to generalize so everyone can use this two commands can solve everyone problem.

```
sudo chown -R $USER var/cache
sudo chown -R $USER var/logs
```

Further Info: `$USER` automatically replaces your username so it can be used by anyone.

Answer (score -2):

Just delete log and cache directories, then recreate them.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).