# Runtime Exception: unable to create cache directory Google App Engine Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, google-app-engine, caching

I am working with google's app engine Symfony HelloWorld example from https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/symfony-hello-world with source taken from Github.

I have the basic case working, but when I update the AppKernal for a production release I get a fatal error in cloudstorage. The only change is in app.php from `$kernel = new AppKernel();` to `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);`

This produces the error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to create the cache directory (gs://symfony-sp-bucket15//symfony/cache) ' in /base/data/home/apps/s~symfony-starter-project/15.390142223904071434/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2632

I have tried clearing the cache and memcache.  I've also consulted related links such as: [RuntimeException: Unable to create the cache directory (/var/www/sonata/app/cache/dev)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20127884/runtimeexception-unable-to-create-the-cache-directory-var-www-sonata-app-cach), but these do not resolve the issue on Google's App Engine.  Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Since GCS is emulated when you are testing locally, you should check if 'symfony-sp-bucket15' actually exists in your project (Storage -> Browser in the Developers Console). You may need to create it or specify a different bucket name in your config.